# how to create an customize facebook sharing button

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

Please i search a lot in how to create a shared button in my website, i found some articles but i didn't make it 
i want  that facebook icon takes me to the frame window 
i added that script

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '315274705610837',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

but what exactly should do next
Thanks for help

Comment: You can call the share function by yourself [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/examples) so the button can looks like whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are trying the WebSDK as documented in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

But you do not actually need to do that for a custom share button... See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

Comment: Yes but i want to make a img inside div that contain facebook icon and take me to the sharing frame window instead of the default link giving by facebook itself